# Apply a Pig UDF to every column

Tags: python, hive, apache-pig

I am trying to write a Python UDF in Pig to clean all the columns in a table. The examples of Pig UDFs that I have seen all work on a single column.

In Hive, I can do something like,

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE <table_name>
SELECT TRANSFORM (
 col1, col2, col3
)
USING 'clean.py'
AS (
 col1, col2, col3
);
```

This cleans all columns at once. Wondering if I can make something similar in Pig. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the entire row without a separator using PigStorage() and call the UDF on that.

```
REGISTER CleanUDF.jar;
DEFINE CleanText com.soc.pig.udf.CleanText;

A = LOAD '/user/rawData.txt' USING PigStorage();
B = FOREACH A GENERATE CleanText($0);
DUMP B;
```

Based on your separator you can split and implement your logic inside the UDF which all columns you need to clean.